# Find and replace words between characters

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I am working on this project, below is a replica of a string that I'm working on, but it is only for example purpose so it doesn't make much sense. My goal is to figure out the word between `<ebm>` and `</ebm>` and replace it accordingly.

```
var string = "“You know you're in love when <ebm>img-1</ebm> you can't fall asleep because reality <ebm>img-2</ebm>is finally better than your dreams.” <ebm>img-3</ebm>"
```

For example, if the word between  `<ebm>` and `</ebm>` is

```
"img-1" then replace it with "Strong" (remove the <ebm> tags)
"img-2" then replace it with "Weak" (remove the <ebm> tags)
"img-3" then replace it with "Nice" (remove the <ebm> tags)
```

I cannot just simply use string.replace() because I have hundred lists of these  words that has to be replaced accordingly. I need to know what's inside the word between  tags so that I can use it to extract the approriate value on my array list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a regex replacement with a callback function:

```js
var terms = {};
terms['img-1'] = 'Strong';
terms['img-2'] = 'Weak';
terms['img-3'] = 'Nice';

var text = "“You know you're in love when <ebm>img-1</ebm> you can't fall asleep because reality <ebm>img-2</ebm>is finally better than your dreams.” <ebm>img-3</ebm>";
text = text.replace(/<ebm>(.+?)<\/ebm>/g, function(match, contents, offset, input_string)
{
    return (terms[contents]);
});

console.log(text);
```

The idea here is to match every `<ebm>...</ebm>` tag, passing each match to a callback function.  We then take the text captured in between the tags, and do a lookup in an associative array, which, for example, maps `img-1` to `Strong`.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for but It's giving me an "undefined" error between the tags.

Comment: @PhilGreene I don't know this API at all, I seem to have it working now.